# How to subset R dataframe by starting and ending row value

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to get the subset of the dataframe from ***Enter*** to ***Exit***.
So in this example, there are two subsets, which i want to store in a temporary DF  (then to count if there is any ***fail*** in it):

[image: Sample DataFrame]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to `split` based on the occurence of 'Enter' into a `list` of `data.frame` (Based on the example showed, 'Enter' occurs after the 'Exit' row)

```
lst1 <- split(df1, cumsum(df1$Event == 'Enter'))
```

Then, we use `lapply/sapply` to loop over the `list` and get the `count`

```
sapply(lst1, function(x) sum(x$Event == 'fail'))
```